# JSF Rendering Issue (Page getting cached)

Tags: jsf

I am facing a strange issue with JSF.
I have developed one controller and bind it to request scope. 
I need to access one jsf page like `http://localhost:8080/selectRule.jsf?type=A` and on the same IE session I want to issue another request like `http://localhost:8080/selectRule.jsf?type=B`

as we can see, only the `type` is changing here. 
This is why I have a ruleController bound to request scope, so that every request, creates the controller and pulls out the data depending upon type. 
I have a `private HtmlSelectOneMenu choices` item in the page. What I see is, somehow only once in the session the getChoices() is getting called. This is what I see

1. For each url, one new ruleController object is getting created.
2. Only first time getChoices() are called. In the subsequent time, if I change the URL in the web browser, the getChoices() method are not getting called though a new controller is getting created.

Note: I am using JSF 1.1

Answer (score 1):

Rather listen on the `value` instead of `binding` if you want to return the component's value.

By the way, the `FacesServlet` is the sole controller. The managed bean just represents the model.